# Make a java class that has a list of itself OR some other variable

Tags: java, jpa

consider this sample class:

```
public class Foo {
    private List<Foo> manyFoos;
    private String Bar;
}
```

I want instances of this class to populate one of both attributes only.
In plain java i would use an interface and make two classes, but i couldn't find a way to annotate this properly for jpa to work (eclipselink).
Is it possible to implement this logic with some clever design techniques or does it require extra code inside the getters und setters, that would cause such a behaviour?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What did you try? Did you try @ManyToMany?

Comment: What do you mean by populate one of both attributes only?

Comment: If there is an instance of Foo, it has either `Bar` or `manyFoos` set - not both.

Comment: Sounds to me that you could subclass Foo: `FooFoos` and `FooBar`. And FooFoos has a field `@ManyToMany private List<Foo> manyFoos`

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to put this rule into your model structure, just implement the rule in your methods, or application.

Comment: Can you explain, why you'd choose this approach over structure rules, please.